# Microsoft Claims TenantId Removed, Changed or unavailable

Tags: oauth, azure-active-directory, claims

I have a website where I login via OAuth and AzureAD.
I aquire my OAuth AuthenticationToken like this:

```
Claim tenantClaim = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(TenantIdClaimType);
if (tenantClaim != null)
{
    string tenantId = tenantClaim.Value;
    string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
    AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Startup.Authority, new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectID));
    ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
    AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(dynamicsUrl, credential, new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));
    return authenticationResult.CreateAuthorizationHeader();
}
```

It worked well all the time. I lost track of the website for about 3 months and it's not working anymore. I debugged through my code and tried to do it "manually". Went on http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid and I saw this message:

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
>   changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Is it removed, renamed or something? I checked AzureAD, everything is still valid (not expired) I even created a new appKey and tried it but it's still not working.

I'm sorry for my bad english I hope you guys understand what I'm asking and what I'm talking about. If you need further informations please let me know.

Thank you for taking the time I appreciate your help.

Best regards,
Nico aka. Myridor

Comment: That schemas.microsoft.com is a URI, not a URL. It's just an identifier :)

Comment: You should debug/log what claims are available on the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

It had nothing to do with the Claims, the problem was the NaiveSessionCache because ADAL updated a method so that it starts a new Thread..

Found my answer here: [HttpContext.Current is null on TokenCache.BeforeAccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43908344/httpcontext-current-is-null-on-tokencache-beforeaccess)