# Microsoft graph authorization code flow - get authorization code from web app programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have created web app to CreateOrGet, Delete, Update onlinemeeting using Microsoft Graph API in C#.

To get authorization code as per link [Get access on behalf of a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user). It returns a webview as HttpClient calls api for AuthCodeGeneration and returns the response, which contains Authcode in browser. I have to manually copy it to execute CreateOrGet, Delete, Update onlinemeeting using Microsoft Graph API.

Is there any way to do this through code in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to handle the "code" and "access token" by your self.

Install [Microsoft Graph .NET SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdk-installation#install-the-microsoft-graph-net-sdk) and implement [Authorization code provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#authorization-code-provider) to get the `authProvider`. Use the `authProvider` to generate the `graphClient`.

```
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
    .Build();

AuthorizationCodeProvider authProvider = new AuthorizationCodeProvider(confidentialClientApplication, scopes);

GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

var onlineMeeting = new OnlineMeeting
{
    StartDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2019-07-12T21:30:34.2444915+00:00"),
    EndDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2019-07-12T22:00:34.2464912+00:00"),
    Subject = "User Token Meeting"
};

await graphClient.Me.OnlineMeetings
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(onlineMeeting);
```

Comment: i tried above code gives err :AuthenticationException: Code: authenticationChallengeRequired
Message: Authentication challange is required.

Comment: @sdsUser Provide your code please. And there should be more detailed error message. Please also share it.

Comment: @sdsUser Looks like you didn't implement an interactive login in your application?

Comment: I copied ur code and pasted it on btn click nothingelse i hv done.Yes,2 err r there:1.ServiceException: Code: generalException
Message: An error occurred sending the request. 2.AuthenticationException: Code: authenticationChallengeRequired
Message: Authentication challange is required.

Comment: No i hv not implemented interactive login bcoz our requirement it after login into our application we should be able to create online meeting with ms teams on btn click using ms graph api.plz guide how to do it.

Comment: @sdsUser Maybe I didn't get it. If you don't implement interactive login, how did you "login into our application"?

Comment: I think i am not clear about interactive login u r talking about to implement.plz guide on it.I login into our web application's login page.can we use the same login as interactive login.if yes plz share code.

Comment: @sdsUser It depends on how you integrate AAD authorization to the web app. Could you provide me with the document about that?

Comment: @sdsUser Anyway, you can refer to this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/msgraph-build-aspnetmvc-apps/5-exercise-add-auth. If there is any concern while following this sample, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: I am trying will let u know

Comment: Hi @Allen I tried ur code as given in document.Very nicely explained.Now using beta graph api i am trying to create online meeting if request is authenticated.But after executing 'await graphServiceClient.Me.OnlineMeetings.CreateOrGet(externalId, null, dateTimeOffsetSTART, meetingParticipants, dateTimeOffsetEND, sSubject).Request().PostAsync();' Getting err "httpContext was null." inside BeforeAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args).plz guide.

Comment: @sdsUser Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43908344/httpcontext-current-is-null-on-tokencache-beforeaccess.

Comment: I got it worked when i made controller action async like this " public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {var mymeetings = await graphServiceClient.Me.OnlineMeetings.CreateOrGet(id,.."}};Now able to create online meeting using graph and auth code

Comment: @sdsUser Glad to know everything is OK now:)

Comment: The only problem with your answer is that it doesn't work. The link you provided to implement and authorization code provider, is missing a very crucial instruction step. In one of the lines, the code expects the Authorization Code. Can you please tell us HOW to get that Authorization code?

Comment: I don't get it. A key thing to implement this code, is to implement a authorization code provider. And if you follow the link, the code there expects an authorization code. The user is already logged in, how do you get the auth code? Do I have to force the user to log in again? Or do I have to do all of my Microsoft Graph operations upon login??