# Error: Unauthenticated, Must be authenticated to use '/drive' syntax - When getting an item using rest api (graph)

Tags: c#, onedrive, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I am using a windows application to upload and download a file from **onedrive api**.

> Code to retrieve token (This code is directly downloaded from azure portal after creating an app registration)

```
    string graphAPIEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me";
    string[] scopes = new string[] { "user.read" };
    AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
    
    var app = App.PublicClientApp;
    ResultText.Text = string.Empty;
    TokenInfoText.Text = string.Empty;
    var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
    var firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();
    try
    {
             authResult = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, firstAccount)
               .ExecuteAsync();
    }
    catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"MsalUiRequiredException: {ex.Message}");
                        try
                        {
                            authResult = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                                .WithAccount(firstAccount)
                                .WithParentActivityOrWindow(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle) // optional, used to center the browser on the window
                                .WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount)
                                .ExecuteAsync();
                        }
                        catch (MsalException msalex)
                        {
                            ResultText.Text = $"Error Acquiring Token:{System.Environment.NewLine}{msalex}";
                        }
}
```

> This is the code to get the download url of an item from onedrive api

```
string url="https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/Qwerty/test.txt";
string token=authResult.AccessToken;
var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
            System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response;
            try
            {
                var request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage(System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get, url);
                //Add the token in Authorization header
                request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Response cls = new Response();
                    cls.Success = "TRUE";
                    cls.Method = "GetAllFiles";
                    cls.Data = content;
                    return cls;
                }
                else
                {
                    Response cls = new Response();
                    cls.Success = "FALSE";
                    cls.Method = "GetAllFiles";
                    cls.Data = content;
                    return cls;
                }
```

Im getting this error "Must be authenticated to use '/drive' syntax". this app works with one of my personal app registration . but when i use the below app registration its strating to show this error. i followed the exact same steps in creating the app registration i dnt knw why this error.
client id with error: 463921cd-72a3-495d-847e-259b99dda89e
**Please help me**
[This is the sreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8TTZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to download the contents of a DriveItem, you must add one of the following permissions to call this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_get_content?view=odsp-graph-online). And you need to add the delegated permission when using `/me`. The scope in your code is also changed with permission.

[image]

Then you could refer to the code sample:

C# with graph SDK: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63806689/13308381

---

Try to follow [these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) in Postman:

1.Request an authorization code

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={client_id}&scope={scope}
  &response_type=code&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}
```

2.Request an access token

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id={client_id}&scope={scope}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&client_secret={client_secret}
&code={code}&grant_type=authorization_code
```

3.Call Microsoft Graph API

```
GET /me/drive/root:/{item-path}:/content
```

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click on the mark option beside the reply to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.), see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: i added the permissions but still im getting unauthenticated error message. :'(

Comment: Hi, @EfficientMallu. Plz try to get access token and call API with Postman or Graph Explorer.  And make sure you have added the required permission in app registrations. ps: After adding the permission, it needs about 10 minutes to make it work.

Comment: Thank you  @Pamela Peng . I have found the answer . your answer helped me a lot but because its not the exact cause i haven't ticked it but i have upvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the issue. issue was when creating an access token we need specify scopes like(Files.Read,Files.ReadWrite,etc (add whatever we need)) and then use the same token for downloading's a file and it was ok